# Swap csv row and column in Python (complicated as I have lists)

Tags: python, csv

This is my code in trying to create a csv file.
The code essentially works but I need the rows into columns.
**Column 1: artist

Column 2: album

Column 3: song title

Column 4: URL of song lyrics

Column 5: Song lyrics

Column 6: Most common 3 words in the song**

```
# creates a list of all the entries that we need in the csv file
# they are all lists
allRows = [artist_name],albumTitleList,songTitleList,songList, \
inputLyricsList,count

# I thought zipping will make the rows into columns, but it doesn't,
# and without it, each letter takes up a cell, instead of a word.
zipped =zip(allRows)

# write out the csv
myfile = open('test.csv', 'wb' )
wr = unicodecsv.writer(myfile, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
for val in zipped:
    wr.writerows(val)
```

I have tried using just allRows instead of zipped, it didn't work.
I have also tried    `zipped = zip(*allRows)`    but it didn't work either.

Comment: Can you include the first 5 lines of csv and desired result to test?